# i3-nagbar not executing from systemd service(display and xauthority has been set)

Tags: systemd

I want to write a cron job replacement in systemd using timers to check my battery level and give me a warning when it is below a certain level using i3-nagbar. I looked at the other questions in stackoverflow but they were all solved by setting the display and xauthority variables which I have done.

Service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Low battery warning

[Service]

Environment="DISPLAY=:0" "XAUTHORITY=/home/leon/.Xauthority"
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/leon/.miscellaneous/battery.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Timer file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Low battery timer

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=5min
OnBootSec=0min

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent
echo $POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS
echo $POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY
if [ "$POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS" == "Discharging" ]; then
    if [ $POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY -lt 30 ]; then
        echo "low battery"
        /bin/i3-nagbar -t warning -m "Warning: Low Battery" &
    elif [ $POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY -lt 10 ]; then
        systemctl suspend
    fi
fi
```

systemctl status batt_warn.service:

```
Apr 20 21:32:12 krypton systemd[1]: Starting Low battery warning...
Apr 20 21:32:12 krypton systemd[1]: batt_warn.service: Succeeded.
Apr 20 21:32:12 krypton systemd[1]: Started Low battery warning.
Apr 20 21:32:12 krypton bash[9770]: Discharging
Apr 20 21:32:12 krypton bash[9770]: 27
Apr 20 21:32:12 krypton bash[9770]: low battery
```

It should give me a warning when battery is low using i3-nagbar. Currently the script is being executed periodically but the nag-bar doesn't seem to appear.